# What does it mean "double-digit lead"

Tags: meaning

I see that on the presidential election news these days that "Trump holds double-digit lead in 2 national polls", I don't understand what it means.

Comment: double digit lead means having a lead of not less than 2 digits.

Comment: he's got a lead of 10 points

Answer (score 1):

The convention in the reporting of opinion polls is that the results are given as percentages. If a candidate is reported as having a "2-point lead", it means x+2 percent of the electorate intend to vote for that candidate, as opposed to x percent intending to vote for the leading rival.

A "double-digit lead" means the difference in percentages is in double-digits, i.e. greater than 10%.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, "10% or greater", rather than "greater than 10%".

Comment: Double-digit, meaning: it takes two digits to write it.

Comment: Just to be even more pedantic, to write it in base 10.  :)